# beginner question on homomorphism (introductory abstract algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra

For a group $G$ Define, $K(x) = \{g \in G : \operatorname{ord} (g) = x\}$, let $I: G \to H$ be a group homomorphism. Show that

a) if the order of $g$ is n then the $\operatorname{ord} I(g) \leq n$

I have managed to show part (i)

b) if $I$ is injective then $I(K(n)) \subset H(n)$ for $n\geq 1$

I am stuck with part (b). I have no idea how to proceed and use the fact that $I$ is injective to prove the result. Any guidance is fine as I could not find a solution online. For reference, I am using introductory to abstract by Keith Nicholson but I have no solution for the problem.

Sorry for my latex issues; I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Show that if there is an $x\in K(n)$ such that $I(x)\notin H(n)$, then $I$ is not injective. Remember, you know that $\operatorname{ord}I(x)\le n$, so your hypothesis here amounts to saying that $\operatorname{ord}I(x)<n$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the hint, however I am not able to proceed. I just don't seem to know what to do with it. You say that $ord I(x) \leq n$ means my hypothesis amounts to saying $ord I(x) < n$ How did you get that? Could you perhaps give another nudge in the right direction as I can't seem to move past this.

Comment: @sarah: You have an $x\in K(n)$, meaning that $\operatorname{ord}x=n$. You want to show that $\operatorname{ord}I(x)=n$ as well. Suppose not. In part (a) you proved that $\operatorname{ord}I(x)\le n$, so it must be that $\operatorname{ord}I(x)<n$. Use that to show that $I$ cannot be injective. HINT: If $\operatorname{ord}I(x)<n$, is it possible for $I(x),I(x^2),\ldots,I(x^n)$ all to be different elements of $H$?