# Order of elements under injective homomorphism and isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Define $G(n)= \{ g \in G: ord(g)=n \}$

Need to show (i): if $f: G \to H$ is an injective homomorphism, then $f(G(n)) \subset H(n)$ for all $n \ge 1$,

and (ii): $\lvert G(n) \rvert = \lvert H(n) \rvert$ if $f$ isomorphic.

My intuition is that if $f$ is injective, then all elements in $G$ of order n, i.e. $G(n)$, get mapped one-to-one to $f(G(n))$, but since the range of $f$ may be smaller than H, there are possibly other elements in $H$ with order $n$ , hence a subset relation. If $f$ is an isomorphism then all elements of order $n$ in $H$, i.e. $H(n)$, will have come from $G(n)$ via $f$, so the number of elements of ordern $n$ will be the same for each group.

Does this suffice as a proof or is it too hand-wavy?...

Comment: It’s a bit hand-wavy. See the hint that I gave for [this question on the same exercise](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111119/beginner-question-on-homomorphism-introductory-abstract-algebra/1111129#1111129).

Comment: You can't use arguments based on the number of elements of order $n$, because that might be infinite. Also, you do not seem to have made any attempt to prove (i).

Comment: @Derek: Alex alread [asked about (i)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111121/show-that-group-homomorphism-reduces-the-order-of-an-element) and got an answer.